# python plt x axis scale is different from data

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data set looks like:

```
     Month  DeviceType  AvgRevenue
0   201608  desktop     3.029642
1   201608  mobile      0.197588
2   201608  tablet      1.575810
3   201609  desktop     2.352156
4   201609  mobile      0.182009
```

And I try to draw a plot to visualize it, however, the x-axis is different from the original data, since my x-axis should be Year and month, the x-axis that the plot shows is not reasonable...How can I correct this? Thanks!!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in device.groupby('DeviceType'):
    group.plot('Month', y='AvgRevenue', ax=ax, label=name)
```

[image]

Comment: Your month data looks like a number or string so there is no meaning relational meaning. Do you want these to be a `datetime` dtype? If so then convert them: `device['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(device['Month'], format='%Y%M')` if it's a number then you need to cast first: `device['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(device['Month'].astype(str), format='%Y%M')`

Comment: @EdChum Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by converting my device['Month'] into date time :
`device['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(device['Month'], format='%Y%M')`